# Documents meta data in SharePoint Foundation 2013

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have a basic requirement and I'm not sure how to implement it in SharePoint Foundation 2013.
Users need to associate meta data with documents when they upload these documents. Users want to specify the document semantic type (Contract, purchase order, ...  ) and for each type users want to specify meta data ( for contracts: start date, customer name,... ).

Is this achievable using SharePoint Foundation 2013 ? 
If yes, how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Creating content types**

1. Open Site Settings -> Site Content Types -> Click Create
2. Name = Contract
3. Parent Content Type = "Document Content Types" and Select "Document
4. Put this site content type into. Select new group and name it. This way you can group all your custom content types
5. From the next page click on "Add from new site column"
6. Give a column name ex: Start Date
7. Select the column type
8. Put this site column into: New Group
9. Click Ok
10. Add other site columns related to content type "Contract"

Do step 1 to 10 for Purchase Order

Once you have created all these content types.

1. Open up the document library, Library Settings
2. Click Add from existing site content types
3. Select site content types from: Select the content type group you created in step (3)
4. Select Contract and click Add
5. Do step 4 for all other content types you have created

Now when user add a new document or upload a document, they can choose the content type. And based on the selection various site columns (meta data) will get displayed.

Comment: Thanks Amal, Do you know how these fields can be used in search ?

Comment: Off topic. Please create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should use content types:https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/Create-or-customize-a-content-type-27eb6551-9867-4201-a819-620c5658a60f